# Drawing Multiple Frame got weird Situation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

While trying to draw multiple Frame keeping same `HeightRequest`,`WidthRequest` and `CornerRadius`, It gives perfect Circular Frame only for that Frame having the highest `HeightRequest`. Anybody knows What's happening here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CircleButton"
             x:Class="CircleButton.MainPage">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="40"  BackgroundColor="Orange" Padding="0" OutlineColor="MediumPurple"></Frame>
        <Frame HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" CornerRadius="60" BackgroundColor="SkyBlue" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Orange"></Frame>
        <Frame HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" CornerRadius="80" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Magenta"></Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[Output is shown in Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDrJq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your StackLayout use this

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
```

Then in your Frame also use this can be your want:

```
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
```

So the code is like this:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <!--Modify here -->
            <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Orange" Padding="0" OutlineColor="MediumPurple"></Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" CornerRadius="60" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="SkyBlue" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Orange"></Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" CornerRadius="80" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Magenta"></Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Then the result is right here.

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

There is no space for drawing all the frames, that's why it get's cut.

Try setting the StackLayout to FillAndExpand, and then, center all the frames within:

```
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="40" VerticalOptions="Center" 
BackgroundColor="Orange" Padding="0" OutlineColor="MediumPurple"></Frame>
        <Frame HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" VerticalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="60" BackgroundColor="SkyBlue" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Orange"></Frame>
        <Frame HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" VerticalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="80" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Padding="0" OutlineColor="Magenta"></Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```